# Updating duplicate records on the basis of date, so no two dates are same

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, ssis

```
Hkey | Observation dt|      Retriment_dt | Name |Code | Masterkey
---------+------------+------
23        10/8/2018        01/01/3030     Sam     XYZ       99
23        10/8/2018        01/01/3030     Sam     XYZ       98
23        10/8/2018        01/01/3030     Sam     XYZ       97
21        11/8/2018        01/01/3030     JOHN   TGI        65 
21        11/8/2018        01/01/3030     JOHN   TGI        64
21        11/8/2018        01/01/3030     JOHN   TGI        63
30        11/8/2018        01/01/3030     Chris  MNY        70
```

Ok, so assume i have this table and my table total count is over a million i want to update the table (`Observation dt` and `retirement dt` ) for the duplicate rows - I dont want to update all the observation dates to the same date but i want them to be different by a day. I have manually inputed it below. How can i do it in Sql or SSIS or in any programming language. This is Mssql Db table. I am new to sql and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Combination of `HKey` and `Observation_dt` is the primary key and when i apply the constraint it will throw an error, so i am trying to retire all the duplicate records by changing both `retirement_dt` and `observation_dt`. `Retirement dt` will be todays date and `observation_dt` can be any date-1 (incrementally for each duplicate date)

What it should look like when the code runs

```
Hkey | Observation dt|      Retriment_dt | Name |Code | Masterkey
---------+------------+------
23        10/8/2018        01/01/3030     Sam     XYZ       99
23        10/7/2018        12/17/2018     Sam     XYZ       98
23        10/6/2018        12/17/2018     Sam     XYZ       97
21        11/8/2018        01/01/3030     JOHN   TGI        65 
21        11/7/2018        12/17/2018     JOHN   TGI        64
21        11/6/2018        12/17/2018     JOHN   TGI        63
30        11/8/2018        01/01/3030     Chris  MNY        70
```

Comment: You mention in your question that the table is a MySQL db but you have tagged the question with SQL Server, SSIS, and TSQL.  Which is it please?

Comment: My apologies martin i meant it was mssql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker did this in a similar way, But thank you for the replies. I have posted the code used.

```
SELECT [healthplanentryhistory_avi_hkey]
    ,[effective_date]
    ,[expiration_date]
    ,[healthplanentryhistoryid]
    ,[hospitalmasterid]
    ,[plancode]
    ,[plangeneration]
    ,[code]
    ,[pawvalue]
    ,[quantitycoveredbyplan]
    ,[healthplanentrymasterid]
    ,[healthplanentryid]
    ,[healthplanid]
    ,[lastupdate]
    ,[origpawvalue]
    ,[active_ind]
    ,[hash_diff]
    ,[source_sys_id]
    ,[create_date]
    ,[update_date]
    ,cnt
    ,Rank
INTO ##tmphph
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [healthplanentryhistory_avi_hkey]) AS cnt
        ,RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [healthplanentryhistory_avi_hkey] ORDER BY healthplanentryhistoryid DESC
            ) AS Rank
    FROM [atf_healthplanentryhistory_avi]
    ) AS t
WHERE t.cnt > 1
    AND t.rank > 1
ORDER BY healthplanentryhistoryid DESC;

---SELECT * FROM ##tmphph where healthplanentryhistory_avi_hkey = 0x039E7D809F8138B703FC9991E9D8F655
MERGE INTO [atf_healthplanentryhistory_avi] atf
USING ##tmphph TEMP
    ON atf.healthplanentryhistory_avi_hkey = TEMP.[healthplanentryhistory_avi_hkey]
        AND atf.effective_date = TEMP.effective_date
        AND atf.healthplanentryhistoryid = TEMP.healthplanentryhistoryid
        AND TEMP.rank > 1
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET atf.effective_date = getdate() - TEMP.rank /*This will update the effective_date to efective_date - rank#*/
            ,expiration_date = getdate() - TEMP.rank
            ,active_ind = 0;

DROP TABLE ##tmphph
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #YourTable

SELECT
    V.Hkey,
    [Observation dt] = CONVERT(DATE, V.[Observation dt]),
    [Retriment_dt] = CONVERT(DATE, V.[Retriment_dt])
INTO
    #YourTable
FROM
    (VALUES
    (23,'2018-08-10','3030-01-01'),
    (23,'2018-08-10','3030-01-01'),
    (23,'2018-08-10','3030-01-01'),
    (21,'2018-08-10','3030-01-01'),
    (21,'2018-08-10','3030-01-01'),
    (21,'2018-08-10','3030-01-01'),
    (30,'2018-08-10','3030-01-01')) V(Hkey, [Observation dt], [Retriment_dt])

;WITH DuplicateRecords AS
(
    SELECT
        T.HKey,
        T.[Observation dt]
    FROM
        #YourTable T
    GROUP BY
        T.HKey,
        T.[Observation dt]
    HAVING
        COUNT(1) > 1
),
RowNumber AS
(
    SELECT
        T.Hkey,
        T.[Observation dt],
        T.[Retriment_dt],
        RowNumberByHkey = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Hkey ORDER BY T.[Observation dt], T.[Retriment_dt])
    FROM
        #YourTable AS T
        INNER JOIN DuplicateRecords AS D ON
            T.Hkey = D.Hkey AND
            T.[Observation dt] = D.[Observation dt]
),
UpdatedValues AS
(
    SELECT
        R.Hkey,
        R.[Observation dt],
        R.[Retriment_dt],
        NewObservationDT = DATEADD(
            DAY,
            -1 * (R.RowNumberByHkey - 1),
            R.[Observation dt]),
        NewRetirementDT = GETDATE(),
        R.RowNumberByHkey
    FROM
        RowNumber AS R
),
RecordsToUpdate AS
(
    -- Need a row number to be able to update correctly, since the record is duplicated (need an ID to join)
    SELECT
        T.Hkey,
        T.[Observation dt],
        T.[Retriment_dt],
        RowNumberByHkey = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Hkey ORDER BY T.[Observation dt], T.[Retriment_dt])
    FROM
        #YourTable AS T
)
UPDATE T SET
    [Observation dt] = R.NewObservationDT,
    [Retriment_dt] = R.NewRetirementDT
FROM
    RecordsToUpdate AS T
    INNER JOIN UpdatedValues AS R ON
        T.HKey = R.HKey AND
        T.[Observation dt] = R.[Observation dt] AND
        T.RowNumberByHkey = R.RowNumberByHkey




SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #YourTable AS T 
ORDER BY 
    T.Hkey, 
    T.[Observation dt] DESC
```

Result:

```
Hkey    Observation dt  Retriment_dt
21      2018-08-10      2018-12-18
21      2018-08-09      2018-12-18
21      2018-08-08      2018-12-18
23      2018-08-10      2018-12-18
23      2018-08-09      2018-12-18
23      2018-08-08      2018-12-18
30      2018-08-10      3030-01-01
```

It was a little tricky because you need to update duplicate records with different values each, so you need to generate some kind of unique ID (I used row number) to be able to match them.

The way to generate different days was to apply a `DATEADD` with the row number, which was partitioned by `HKey`. This generates different days with 1 day difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using Temp table:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
hkey Int,
Observation Date,
Retriment Date
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
(23,'2018-10-08','3030-01-01'),
(23,'2018-10-08','3030-01-01'),
(23,'2018-10-08','3030-01-01'),
(21,'2018-11-08','3030-01-01'),
(21,'2018-11-08','3030-01-01'),
(21,'2018-11-08','3030-01-01'),
(30,'2018-11-08','3030-01-01')


Select Row_Number() OVER(Order By (Select Null)) As raworder,*  Into #temp From #tbl

Select hkey,
        DateAdd(Day,-Row_Number() Over (Partition By hkey Order By hkey)+1 , Observation) As newDT,  
        Case When (Row_Number() Over (Partition By hkey Order By hkey) = 1) Then Retriment Else Convert(Date,GetDate()) End As Retriment
    From #temp
   Order By raworder
```

Result:

```
hkey    newDT       Retriment
23      2018-10-08  3030-01-01
23      2018-10-07  2018-12-18
23      2018-10-06  2018-12-18
21      2018-11-08  3030-01-01
21      2018-11-07  2018-12-18
21      2018-11-06  2018-12-18
30      2018-11-08  3030-01-01
```